# Is it possible to disable an ImageButton when processing?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to disable an ImageButton when running a process?

I found a way to disable a Button when processing, doing this:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

           Dim strProcessScript As String = "this.value='Processing...';this.disabled=true;"
           btnProcess.Attributes.Add("onclick", (strProcessScript + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnProcess, "").ToString))

        End If
End Sub
```

But it didn't work for ImageButton.

Also, I tried this code for disabling an Imagebutton:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

           Dim strProcessScript As String = "this.value='Processing...';this.disabled=true;"
           btnProcess.Attributes.Add("onclick", (strProcessScript + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnProcess, "").ToString) + ";return false;")

        End If
End Sub
```

Neither of both ones makes ImageButton to be disabled when processing, but it works for Button.

Answer (score 0):

this suits better for full postback solution, if you are using ajax, I'd recommend to consider a jquery plugin or any other javascript plugin you can search for, saying that well here´s a small work around:

you need to use the [onClientClick](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_onclientclick.asp) event that's provided OOB for the image button, it's easier to manage due to it's directly tied to the onlick event over the client and there's no nee to registar a custom client event when clicking the button.

all you need to do is passing your code to the onClientClick event

```
<asp:ImageButton  runat="server" ID="BtnSubmit" 
  OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Processing...';" 
  UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
  OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" 
  Text="Submit Me!" />
```

take a look to [this solution](http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/)